# practical problem when computing the probabilities of a normally distributed sample

Tags: normal-distribution, software

I am trying to implement some paper, where I have an iterative scheme where I have to compute the probabilities from a univariate normal distribution as usual:

The python code is:

```
np.exp(-(sample_model_residuals ** 2)/(2 * sigma ** 2))/(sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))
```

My issue is that the sample_model_residuals get too large sometimes and the exponential calculation overflows.

[EDIT]:

I will try and demonstrate why I need this calculation. So, the application is that I have two images which are 1000x1000 in size and I have extracted some features in them which are located at (x, y) where both x and y are between 0 and 999 (spatial locations).

Now, I have matched these features up using some distance criteria (the features are more than the spatial components) and using these matches I have fitted a spatial transform (which is just a rotation and translation transform).

The challenge is that some of these matches are not reliable and I want to only use matches that are reliable to fit this transformation. As part of this candidate transformation models get evaluated and this involves computing this normal probability at some point where these models represent the distance between the matched point and the point achieved after applying the candidate transformation. When the points are mismatched (coming from the clutter distribution) these distances can be quite large and this is where the exponential is failing.

A numerical example would be:

```
import numpy as np
residuals = np.normal(100, 1)*1000
sigma = 20
np.exp(-(residuals ** 2)/(2 * sigma ** 2))/(sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))
```

Comment: Isn't there a minus sign missing in the exponent? (Depending on how things overflow, this might not solve your problem, but this is the first thing to check.)

Comment: oops. good catch. Sorry it was a typing error,

Comment: With this correction, I think it would be useful to develop a numerical example that shows the overflow. What are the values of sample_model_residuals and sigma that python can't handle? Also, how accurate does your result have to be?

Comment: Overflow is impossible for this calculation, because the argument of the exponential cannot possibly exceed $0$. Could you please give us a more accurate description of how the exponential is "failing"?

Comment: show an example which overflows, i.e. an example of the residual and $\sigma$ and other parameters, AND the actual error message

Comment: Sorry I had made a mistake with the negative sign missing and it all made the problem. Should I delete the question or leave it here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first easy fix is to replace $e^{-x^2/\sigma^2}$ with $e^{-(x/\sigma)^2}$.

If this is not enough, come back, I'll tell you what to do next

Comment: This would solve a problem with overflow of the *square* (which is unlikely to occur).  It does not address the question, which describes a problem with computing the *exponential.*

Comment: I doubt that it's exponential that is overflowing. I think it's very large $\sigma$, which prompts very large $x$ observations, then it blows up in the square.

Comment: exponent does overflow. In python, if you do `np.exp(1000)`, you get +inf. I added an answer based on what I did...not sure if it is correct though..

Comment: That's exactly, what I'm coming to. You should not get there to start with, if you do what I showed you. How likely to get 1000 in standard normal? It's basically probability ZERO. Your $\sigma$ must be 500, then it's only $2\sigma$ which is about 10% probability

Comment: Ok, yes, I get it now and my solution was also incorrect. Thank you, I see your point now...

Comment: Another solution is to always work with standard normal, i.e. use `np.normal(100,1)` instead of `np.normal(100,1)*1000`, and modify your code to work with this instead of non-standardized normal

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that your problem is not overflow, but underflow. (When the exponent of the np.exp function is less than about -100, I would expect the result to return 0, but it could be that internally an underflow is reported and passed back to the user.)

This calls for a distinction of cases, which could be dependent on the machine on which you are running your tests. But when the exponent is less than about -10, the value is going to be very close to zero, anyway. It is unlikely that you will need more than about 16 digits of accuracy, in which a simple test of the exponent will tell you whether to use your formula or simply return 0.

Comment: As well. I had the minus missing initially which led to a lot of confusion.